# How to hide bottom-navigation-bar in Acces 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

How can I hide this bar (see picture) in Access 2007?

[hide this bar http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/2125/hideob.jpg](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/2125/hideob.jpg)

Comment: Unless Johan wants to hide the navigation bar programmatically. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Form.NavigationButtons` property to `False`.

Comment: Every form has that property, but if it's showing up on table datasheets, the user might want to hide it there, too. In fact, a datasheet is actually an object of type FORM, so it does actually have a NavigationButtons property. But there is no Datasheets collection and you don't get access to these properties through the TableDefs collection. Instead, you have to set Screen.ActiveDatasheet.NavigationButtons = False for each datasheet that you open. If you wrote a wrapper around DoCmd.OpenTable you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

File -> Options -> Current Database -> Navigation Options

uncheck "Show Search Bar"